# Unexpected borders of display:table-cell containers when page is zoomed in

Tags: html, css

I have a strange problem. When I zoom in a page in Chrome and Opera (with Ctrl +), 1 px top white border shows up for all `display:table-cell` containers with image backgrounds.

Firefox does not have this problem.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50a4gj9p/)

Try to zoom in Jsfiddle page to see the problem.

```
100% - OK
110 % - OK
125% - white border
150% - OK
175% - white border
```

In mobile phones these borders are visible even in default 100% zoom.

**Html:**

```
<div class="dzn1">
    <div class="dzn2">
         <div class="dzn3">

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dzn2">
         <div class="dzn4">

    </div>

    </div>
       <div class="dzn2">
         <div class="dzn3">

    </div>
    </div>

       <div class="dzn2">
         <div class="dzn4">

    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.dzn1{display:table;width:300px;}
.dzn2{display:table-row;}
.dzn3{display:table-cell;width:100%;height:50px;vertical-align:middle;
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/vtwr7z6h1/brd1.jpg');}
.dzn4{display:table-cell;width:100%;height:50px;vertical-align:middle;
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/5a465u5xh/brd2.jpg');}
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: Search "rounding error" and look at the solutions to deal with partial-pixel scenarios. Here's a start: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change no-repeat to repeat in your background-image. Your background-image when zoomed is calculated to "half pixels in height", which the browser either rounds or cuts since there is no such thing as a half pixel.

Another possibility is to increase the size of your background images one pixel.

Comment: My example with red and blue lines is only for stackoverflow purposes to demonstrate the problem. I have a tiled photo and can not increase it's size. No-repeat will not solve the problem - the white border will of different colors, and that's all. At least now I understand that it's not a css related problem. Thanks.

Comment: So take it the other way round - decrease the height of your css by one pixel - solved the issue with tiled photo here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes it however if you add a border the same color as the div image it will hide the space:

https://jsfiddle.net/50a4gj9p/1/

```
.dzn3{display:table-cell;width:100%;height:50px;vertical-align:middle;
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center; border-color: red; border-style: solid; background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/vtwr7z6h1/brd1.jpg');}
.dzn4{display:table-cell;width:100%;height:50px;vertical-align:middle;
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center; border-color: blue; border-style: solid; background-image:url('http://s8.postimg.org/5a465u5xh/brd2.jpg');}
```